# Facebook iOS6 integration force reauthentication

Tags: facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I cannot find any info on how (using the new iOS6 FB integration) to force a user to reauthenticate.

Using

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
    [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
}];
```

and setting allowLoginUI to YES just uses the credentials in the iOS FB settings.  I tried doing this with closeAndClearTokenInformation on the FBSession as well, but same result.

I need to present a login view to the user to allow him to login to FB with a different set of credentials than are in the settings.

How do I do this?